# How do i use IE or IE in private mode with powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, powershell-3.0

1) How do I use Internet Explorer with powershell?

2) How do I use Internet Explorer In **Private Mode** with Powershell

Answer (score 5):

I see alot of question about how to use Internet Explorer Com object with 
powershell.

1) Com object/build in Object

```
$IE=New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
```

that mean Create new Object by Com object of IExplorer Application.

Now the variable $IE have the information about the Internet Explorer.

By Default the Website is on hide mode, So we need to change it to visible.

does it Like that:

```
$IE.Visible=$true
```

For navigate to other website you have the function Navigate:

```
$IE.Navigate("https://www.google.co.il/")
```

for check that the website already done to reload the web, we can use the Member/Property **Busy** that have Boolean value of True (not load yet), False (Done load).

Use like that:

```
 while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {sleep -Seconds 2; }
```

For getting Input  from the webs like that one:
[image]

you need get the document object from the IExplorer

```
$docs = $IE.Document
```

now the variable $docs got the Document object.

Now you asking: what should I search there?.

In the Internet Explorer Click F12 and search the Input tab Check:
[image]

Now I know a lot of information about the tab.

Let get The Input In my PowerShell, I know the Input Name is "q",
So Let search by name: (and we only want Select one)

```
$InputTab = $docs.getElementsByName("q") | select -First 1
```

Now we got the Input, Now let put some input:

```
$InputTab.value = "Your Value"
```

Result:
[image]

All in All Code:

```
$IE=New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$IE.Visible=$true
$IE.Navigate("https://www.google.co.il/")
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {sleep -Seconds 2 } 
$docs = $IE.Document
$InputTab = $docs.getElementsByName("q") | select -First 1

$InputTab.value = "Your Value"
```

---

2)
Like IExplorer Object, we have Com object that called "Shell"
That Collect all "Running" com Application

It mean like IExplorer Application there more App such as Explorer(the Folder view) and More and more Com object...

So how I used Shell? And how I use it for IE with "PrivateMode"?

it easy

Create it

```
  $Shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
```

That create Shell object, Now get the All Application by:

```
$Application = $Shell.Windows()
```

Now

$Application variable got all Collection of Com Applcation..

So Only need Create Iexplore with "Private Mode" and then get that Application.

A) Create IExplore (Just run the normal Process with private mode)

```
 Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList ' -private http://Url.Test.NotExist'
```

B) Create Shell App

```
$Shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
```

C) Get All Shell Object

```
$Application = $Shell.Windows()
```

D) Get the Internet Explorer Application by the Shell

```
$IE = $Application | ?{$_.LocationName -like '*google*'} | select -last 1
```

We Done now $IE got the same (1) Question just in PrivateMode

finally) I really Recommend Download [that](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19662)

That will add functions to your **Document Object** like searching with Class Name and more function that i found usefull

Comment: '2' Answer is wonderful idea. never though it could works on Private.. Thank you very much :)